# Can I use Sikuli as an Jython library in my project?

Tags: jython, sikuli

Sikuli is really cool, but it's working in its buildin Jython environment, the Sikuli IDE.

So I m wondering is it possible to import Sikuli as an external library to my Jython library? I saw from Sikuli's website that they have this Python module which provides all Sikuli actions like click and type.  Here is the link: http://sikuli.org/documentation.shtml#doc/pythondoc-python.edu.mit.csail.uid.Sikuli.html

I have tried importing the skiuli-script.jar and add the skiuli-script/Lib to the PYTHONPATH. Then in my spike.py script, I try to do this:

```
import python.edu.mit.csail.uid.Sikuli 

capture() #enter to screen capture mode
```

then when execute the script, I got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /eclipse_3.4.2/workspace/Jython/src/tmplib/libVDictProxy.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /eclipse_3.4.2/workspace/Jython/src/tmplib/libVDictProxy.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I m using Jython 2.2.1 and Mac 10.6.2 (32-bit mode). I have also set to use 32-bit mode first in Java Preference.

Comment: Yes. You can. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302930/can-we-integrate-sikuli-and-pytest-together-for-an-automation-test-solution

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with jython 2.5.1 on win32:

I have to include the win32 dir in the PATH

on your mac installation you have to add the templib Directory to your path

see the sikuli-script.sh

sikuliscript is build to run with jython 2.5.x.

a 2.5 jython is included in the sikuli-script.jar

the test-script :

```
import python.edu.mit.csail.uid.Sikuli as Sikuli

Sikuli.capture() #enter to screen capture mode
```

putting it all together i think the answer is :

YES